# Superscript character in Appcelerator

Tags: android, appcelerator, typography, superscript

I have tried to insert htmltext with superscript tag's to a label in appcelerator/titanium. It's working fine, but I didn't make it, to reduce the font-size of the sup-tag. It has the same font-size as the rest of the label. It will be cut off on the top of the label. Any suggestions how I could fix that?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPCht.png)

Comment: change height of label?

Comment: height is set to "SIZE" (auto) to fit needed size and to get adjusted to center of surrounding container